# Object doesn't get added to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` *`myArray`

I am trying to add the objects to it but no objects get added to it.

**Code :**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;


-(void)viewDidLoad{


  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];

  NSLog(@"Print array :%@",_myArray];

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?
I am a newbee..there might be some silly mistake...Please Help.

Comment: FYI - You have a property, use it. Change all of your references to `_myArray` to `self.myArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy : does that make a difference...I mean what is the difference between _myArray and self.myArray ?

Comment: @Xman What's the difference? It's the difference between using the property and directly accessing the ivar. Using the property potentially has many benefits over directly using the ivar. You get KVO support with the property. The property's getter and setter could perform all kinds of extra functionality depending on how they are implemented. If you are just going to directly access the ivar, then what is the point of bothering with a property to begin with?

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks..you have definitely added something to my knowledge.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup...
You havn't initialized the array..

```
_myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

after that try adding the elements.
**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: yeahh....this worked...so silly me...thanks xman..

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your array yet?

For example:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

  _myArray = [[NSMUtableArray alloc]]init;
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];
  [_myArray addObject:@"One"];

  NSLog(@"Print array :%@",_myArray];

}
```